# why css is not applied in given divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

can you please tell me why css is not applied in my divs.Actually I am taking help of this example .
http://jsfiddle.net/nP5kh/1/

in which **`timestamp count data`** is display.Now I need to use the same concept .usng only div .without using ul li .
I want to know where i miss because my timestamp is not front of data ?

here is my fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/yzaaJ/16/

```
 html+=  '<div style=width:22%; float: left; font-size:18px; line-height:200%; class= RLTLeftDiv ><div   style=width:100%; clear:both; line-height:200%;><div style=width:60%; float:left;  ><b>'+ hours + ":" + minutes + ":" +  seconds+'</b></div><div style=width:40%; float:left; text-align:right; ><b>'+ count +'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></div></div></div><div style=width:78%; float:left; font-size:18px; line-height:200%;  class= RLTRightDiv>'+tenLengthString+'</div>';
```

I think i miss some class that why it is not matching with given example.

Comment: Wow, this is just horrible. All of your styles should be applied using  CSS, not as inline style attributes. Doing it like this makes your code extremely difficult to maintain.

Comment: Let me give you a pice of advice, try to use this concepts: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript.

Comment: @netinept while correct, it's not always the case.

Comment: also styles are not classes and your fiddle has no classes defined

Comment: i think table elements are better for this example.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Just wondering, any specific example?

Comment: @A.Wolff just for example if as an external JS application. Even than inline is pretty inferior than creating a function that will apply `style` to a selector or tags directly in the document, but one might want t odo it exactly that way: *without a stylesheet*

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan That's making sense, thx for input!

Answer (score 5):

Stick your inline style in quotation marks:

```
 <div style="width:22%; ...."
```

Edit: In fact, stick all your HTML attribute values in quotation marks

```
<div style="width:22%; float: left; font-size:18px; line-height:200%;" class="RLTLeftDiv"></div>
```

Also, consider styling with a CSS sheet, rather than inline styles:

```
<div class="RLTLeftDiv"></div>

.RLTLeftDiv {
    width:22%;
    float: left;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:200%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in your `style` attribute in quotes:

`<div style="width:22%; float: left; font-size:18px; line-height:200%;" class= RLTLeftDiv >`

Answer (score 0):

Everyone else was right you need to put your styles in ""

I have updated your fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/yzaaJ/17/

```
 <div style="width:22%; float: left; font-size:18px; line-height:200%;" class="RLTLeftDiv"><div   style="width:100%; clear:both; line-height:200%;"><div style="width:60%; float:left;"  ><b>'+ hours + ":" + minutes + ":" +  seconds+'</b></div><div style="width:40%; float:left; text-align:right;" ><b>'+ count +'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></div></div></div><div style="width:78%; float:left; font-size:18px; line-height:200%;" class= "RLTRightDiv">'+tenLengthString+'</div>'
```

You also need your classes in "" as well

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more or less what your trying to do. [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ax2LW/1/)

js snippet from your original code, cleaned up:

```
  html += '<div class="X">' + 
          ' <div class="RLTLeftDiv">' + 
          '  <div class="Time">' + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + '</div>' + 
          '  <div class="Count">' + count + '</div>' + 
          '  <div class="TLS" >' + tenLengthString + '</div>' + 
          ' </div>' +
          '</div>';
```

associated CSS:

```
.X{
    width:300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.RLTLeftDiv {
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:200%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.Time {
    width:60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
}
.Count {
    width:20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:right;
}
.TLS {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:200%;
}
```